# Helmholtz resonance

Tags: acoustics, resonance

I conducted my own Helmholtz resonance experiment with a glass voss bottle. The graph I obtained when plotting my experimental values of f against the reciprocal of square root V is plotted on the graph using the red squares[image]

The graph of the theoretical values that I'm supposed to get when using the Helmholtz formula for my specific bottle dimensions is plotted using the opaque red circles.
Im not quite sure as to why specifically my graph deviates like that from the ideal 'inversely proportional line'. Can someone please explain what factors contribute to my graph being shaped like that? Is this a systematic error or random? 
I did my own bit of research and found out that this might be due to the port length being greater in a real resonator but I don't quite understand the concept fully. To me, this makes sense as to why the graph doesn't cross the origin, but why is the slope different? Please help.

Comment: Eyeballing it, it looks like you actually have a systematic error: it sure seems like each one of your squares is *about* the same distance below the corresponding circles as the other squares, except for the outlier at the top right.  However, without knowledge of your particular setup, it's hard to determine what might be the source of both systematic and random errors in your experiment.

Comment: Look up the "end correction factor" for measuring the speed of sound by creating a resonance in a pipe. There will be a similar correction for the neck of your resonator, though it will depend on the exact shape. Note that Helmholtz's original design https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_resonance#/media/File:Helmholtz_resonator.jpg had a very small area for the neck which will minimize this effect.

Comment: By the way, when you talk about the "port length" being a little longer, is this the same as an end correction at the opening (i.e. the pressure node for the standing wave inside the resonator is actually a little *outside* the mouth of the opening)? If so, this could lead to the systematic error, because this would cause longer wavelengths and hence smaller frequencies for the resonant modes.

Comment: @march my setup was literally just a glass 855cm^3 Voss bottle with a microphone pointed at it. I blew into the bottle and recorded the frequencies on a spectrum analyzer that was connected to the microphone through my computer. The bottle itself is almost a perfect cylinder but has a slightly concaved bottom (flanged I think is the proper term for it) there is only a slight slope from the body of the bottle to it's neck.

Comment: @march also, talking by port length, I was talking about the end correction. If I am to ignore the last point and assume its an outlier as you suggested, the slope of the graph would be correct but now the y-intercept would be negative. This suggests that the standing wave inside the resonator is actually a little inside the opening and not outside, right? If the y- intercept was positive, it would be outside. i am only a high school student so I have never been taught this in school, I hope you can clarify this concept for me.

Comment: If the node is just outside the resonator, you get larger wavelengths (think about fitting a standing wave on a string: a longer string means a larger wavelength). If the wavelengths are larger, then the corresponding frequencies must be smaller.  I don't know if the end correction is enough to account for the size of the systematic error, but it's a possible explanation. Also: never ignore outliers unless you can carefully argue that the outlier should be discarded, based on knowledge of the *source* of the extra error in that outlier.

Comment: @march Wavelength does not matter for a Helmholtz resonator, there is no node. The end correction in this case is about 0.7 times the diameter of the opening, because also the air just outside contributes to the mass of the mass-spring system.